# Swiper slide, вывел стрелки за слайды, есть проблема, если слайдов меньше, то скрипт не работает и стрелки не выводит, но остались отступы от стрелок

Tags: java, swiper

Вывел стрелки отдельно, по стандарту они шли сверху на картинках.
Появилась проблема, допустим если я поставил чтобы 4 слайда выводило, то скрипт срабатывает и показывает что можно листать и выводит стрелки, а если я удалю одну фотку или пару, то у меня выходит 3-2 слайда и скрипт не срабатывает уже, ибо листать нечего, но как быть с отступами которые остались после стрелок.

Может быть я не правильно реализовал отступы.
Или нужно что-то делать, типа проверку, если стрелки показываются, то делать отступ, применять класс, а если стрелок нет, то не применяем класс.

Кто ставил, кто настраивал и мудрил с этим слайдером **Swiper slide**

Офф сайт: https://swiperjs.com/

Вот так если слайдера 4 и более. (скрипт работает)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если слайдеров меньше, то скрипт не работает и стрелки не показывает, все ок, но он показывает отступы где должны быть стрелки, вот как-то хочу это и поправить.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рабочий пример пощупать можно тут:
Пример когда слайдеров меньше и видны отступы.
https://jsfiddle.net/vlit/ag14ju8s/455/

А так когда слайдов хватает и скрипт работает и стрелки показывает.
https://jsfiddle.net/vlit/ag14ju8s/456/

Ну либо тут загружаю пример для работы, ставлю все слайды, вы можете удалить парочку, оставить 2 или 3, чтоб увидеть отступы которые остались.

```js
 var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
   slidesPerView: 4,
   spaceBetween: 15, //отступы между слайдами
   navigation: {
     nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
     prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
   },
   breakpoints: {
     700: {
       slidesPerView: 4,
       loopedSlides: 4,
       spaceBetween: 15
     },
     500: {
       slidesPerView: 2,
       loopedSlides: 2,
       spaceBetween: 10
     },
     350: {
       slidesPerView: 1,
       loopedSlides: 1,
       spaceBetween: 20
     }
   }
 });
```

```css
.allblock{
  max-width: 900px;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px;
}
.block-left{
  width:60%;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.block-right{
  width:40%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.block-right h2{
  font-size:20px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}


.swiperc{
width: 100%;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.swiper {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.swiper-vertical>.swiper-wrapper {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.swiper-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  transition-property: transform;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.swiper-android .swiper-slide,
.swiper-wrapper {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
}

.swiper-pointer-events {
  touch-action: pan-y;
}

.swiper-pointer-events.swiper-vertical {
  touch-action: pan-x;
}

.swiper-slide {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition-property: transform;
}

.swiper-slide-invisible-blank {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.swiper-autoheight,
.swiper-autoheight .swiper-slide {
  height: auto;
}

.swiper-autoheight .swiper-wrapper {
  align-items: flex-start;
  transition-property: transform, height;
}

.swiper-3d,
.swiper-3d.swiper-css-mode .swiper-wrapper {
  perspective: 1200px;
}

.swiper-3d .swiper-cube-shadow,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-right,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-top,
.swiper-3d .swiper-wrapper {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-right,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-top {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 10;
}

.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-left {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-right {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-top {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

.swiper-css-mode>.swiper-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.swiper-css-mode>.swiper-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.swiper-css-mode>.swiper-wrapper>.swiper-slide {
  scroll-snap-align: start start;
}

.swiper-horizontal.swiper-css-mode>.swiper-wrapper {
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.swiper-vertical.swiper-css-mode>.swiper-wrapper {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.swiper-centered>.swiper-wrapper::before {
  content: '';
  flex-shrink: 0;
  order: 9999;
}

.swiper-centered.swiper-horizontal>.swiper-wrapper>.swiper-slide:first-child {
  margin-inline-start: var(--swiper-centered-offset-before);
}

.swiper-centered.swiper-horizontal>.swiper-wrapper::before {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  width: var(--swiper-centered-offset-after);
}

.swiper-centered.swiper-vertical>.swiper-wrapper>.swiper-slide:first-child {
  margin-block-start: var(--swiper-centered-offset-before);
}

.swiper-centered.swiper-vertical>.swiper-wrapper::before {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1px;
  height: var(--swiper-centered-offset-after);
}

.swiper-centered>.swiper-wrapper>.swiper-slide {
  scroll-snap-align: center center;
}

.swiper-virtual.swiper-css-mode .swiper-wrapper::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.swiper-virtual.swiper-css-mode.swiper-horizontal .swiper-wrapper::after {
  height: 1px;
  width: var(--swiper-virtual-size);
}

.swiper-virtual.swiper-css-mode.swiper-vertical .swiper-wrapper::after {
  width: 1px;
  height: var(--swiper-virtual-size);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: swiper-icons;
  src: url('data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64, 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');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-button-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -13px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 90px;
  width: 26px;
  height:26px;
  z-index: 10;
  border-radius: 90px;
  background: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.swiper-button-next:hover,
.swiper-button-prev:hover{
color: #FF2525;
}
.swiper-button-next.swiper-button-disabled,
.swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-disabled {
  opacity: .35;
  cursor: auto;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.swiper-button-next:after,
.swiper-button-prev:after {
  font-family: swiper-icons;
  text-transform: none !important;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-transform: none;
  font-variant: initial;
  line-height: 1;
}
.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-rtl .swiper-button-next {
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
}
.swiper-button-prev:after,
.swiper-rtl .swiper-button-next:after {
  content: 'prev';
}
.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-rtl .swiper-button-prev {
  right:0;
  left: auto;
}
.swiper-button-next:after,
.swiper-rtl .swiper-button-prev:after {
  content: 'next';
}

.swiper-button-lock {
  display: none;
}

.swiper-pagination {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .3s opacity;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 10;
}

.swiper-pagination.swiper-pagination-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

.swiper-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-bullets,
.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-horizontal,
.swiper-pagination-custom,
.swiper-pagination-fraction {
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  transform: scale(.33);
  position: relative;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet-active-main {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet-active-prev {
  transform: scale(.66);
}

.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet-active-prev-prev {
  transform: scale(.33);
}

.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet-active-next {
  transform: scale(.66);
}

.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet-active-next-next {
  transform: scale(.33);
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  width: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-width, var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-size, 8px));
  height: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-height, var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-size, 8px));
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-color, #000);
  opacity: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-opacity, .2);
}

button.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.swiper-pagination-clickable .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet:only-child {
  display: none !important;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  opacity: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-opacity, 1);
  background: var(--swiper-pagination-color, var(--swiper-theme-color));
}

.swiper-pagination-vertical.swiper-pagination-bullets,
.swiper-vertical>.swiper-pagination-bullets {
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(0px, -50%, 0);
}

.swiper-pagination-vertical.swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet,
.swiper-vertical>.swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  margin: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-vertical-gap, 6px) 0;
  display: block;
}

.swiper-pagination-vertical.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic,
.swiper-vertical>.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 8px;
}

.swiper-pagination-vertical.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet,
.swiper-vertical>.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: .2s transform, .2s top;
}

.swiper-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet,
.swiper-pagination-horizontal.swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  margin: 0 var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-horizontal-gap, 4px);
}

.swiper-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic,
.swiper-pagination-horizontal.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.swiper-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet,
.swiper-pagination-horizontal.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  transition: .2s transform, .2s left;
}

.swiper-horizontal.swiper-rtl>.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  transition: .2s transform, .2s right;
}

.swiper-pagination-progressbar {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  position: absolute;
}

.swiper-pagination-progressbar .swiper-pagination-progressbar-fill {
  background: var(--swiper-pagination-color, var(--swiper-theme-color));
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transform-origin: left top;
}

.swiper-rtl .swiper-pagination-progressbar .swiper-pagination-progressbar-fill {
  transform-origin: right top;
}

.swiper-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-progressbar,
.swiper-pagination-progressbar.swiper-pagination-horizontal,
.swiper-pagination-progressbar.swiper-pagination-vertical.swiper-pagination-progressbar-opposite,
.swiper-vertical>.swiper-pagination-progressbar.swiper-pagination-progressbar-opposite {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.swiper-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-progressbar.swiper-pagination-progressbar-opposite,
.swiper-pagination-progressbar.swiper-pagination-horizontal.swiper-pagination-progressbar-opposite,
.swiper-pagination-progressbar.swiper-pagination-vertical,
.swiper-vertical>.swiper-pagination-progressbar {
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.swiper-pagination-lock {
  display: none;
}

.swiper-scrollbar {
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.swiper-horizontal>.swiper-scrollbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1%;
  bottom: 3px;
  z-index: 50;
  height: 5px;
  width: 98%;
}

.swiper-vertical>.swiper-scrollbar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  top: 1%;
  z-index: 50;
  width: 5px;
  height: 98%;
}

.swiper-scrollbar-drag {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.swiper-scrollbar-cursor-drag {
  cursor: move;
}

.swiper-scrollbar-lock {
  display: none;
}

.swiper-zoom-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.swiper-zoom-container>canvas,
.swiper-zoom-container>img,
.swiper-zoom-container>svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.swiper-slide-zoomed {
  cursor: move;
}

.swiper-lazy-preloader {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -21px;
  margin-top: -21px;
  z-index: 10;
  transform-origin: 50%;
  animation: swiper-preloader-spin 1s infinite linear;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 4px solid var(--swiper-preloader-color, var(--swiper-theme-color));
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top-color: transparent;
}

.swiper-lazy-preloader-white {
  --swiper-preloader-color: #fff;
}

.swiper-lazy-preloader-black {
  --swiper-preloader-color: #000;
}

@keyframes swiper-preloader-spin {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.swiper .swiper-notification {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1000;
}

.swiper-free-mode>.swiper-wrapper {
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.swiper-grid>.swiper-wrapper {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.swiper-grid-column>.swiper-wrapper {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.swiper-fade.swiper-free-mode .swiper-slide {
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.swiper-fade .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
  transition-property: opacity;
}

.swiper-fade .swiper-slide .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.swiper-fade .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-fade .swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide-active {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.swiper-cube {
  overflow: visible;
}

.swiper-cube .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-cube .swiper-slide .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.swiper-cube.swiper-rtl .swiper-slide {
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}

.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide-active {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-next,
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-next+.swiper-slide,
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-prev {
  pointer-events: auto;
  visibility: visible;
}

.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-right,
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-top {
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.swiper-cube .swiper-cube-shadow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .6;
  z-index: 0;
}

.swiper-cube .swiper-cube-shadow:before {
  content: '';
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  filter: blur(50px);
}

.swiper-flip {
  overflow: visible;
}

.swiper-flip .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.swiper-flip .swiper-slide .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.swiper-flip .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-flip .swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide-active {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.swiper-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,
.swiper-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-right,
.swiper-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-top {
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.swiper-creative .swiper-slide {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition-property: transform, opacity, height;
}

.swiper-cards {
  overflow: visible;
}

.swiper-cards .swiper-slide {
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.swiper-slide>img {
border: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
}
.swiper-slide>img:hover {
  border: 2px solid #FF2525;
}
.swiper-slide img{
  width: 100%;
}




.allblock{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}







html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;}
html{-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section,summary{display:block;}
audio,canvas,video{display:inline-block;}
audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0;}
[hidden]{display:none;}
a{outline:none; text-decoration: none;}
abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted;}
pre{white-space:pre;white-space:pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word;}
sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;}
sup{top:-0.5em;}
sub{bottom:-0.25em;}
fieldset{border:1px solid #c0c0c0;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em;}
button,input,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:100%;margin:0;}
button,input{line-height:normal;}
button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer;}
button[disabled],input[disabled]{cursor:default;}
input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;}
input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none;}
button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0;}
textarea{overflow:auto;vertical-align:top;}
input:focus,button:focus,select:focus,textarea:focus{outline:none;}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: transparent;}
:focus::-moz-placeholder          {color: transparent;}
:focus:-moz-placeholder           {color: transparent;}
:focus:-ms-input-placeholder      {color: transparent;}
select{cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7.4.1/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="allblock">
  <div class="block-left">
    Левая колонка
  </div>

  <div class="block-right">
  <h2>Куртка зимняя, на меху ноуминус</h2>
    Выберите цветов товара
    <br /><br />

    <div class="swiperc">
      <div class="swiper">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <a class="swiper-slide" href=""><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1b/43/da/1b43da7e99f74011ce4b8c53b00a015f--pop-art-portraits-portrait-art.jpg" /></a>
          <a class="swiper-slide" href=""><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1b/43/da/1b43da7e99f74011ce4b8c53b00a015f--pop-art-portraits-portrait-art.jpg" /></a>
          <a class="swiper-slide" href=""><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1b/43/da/1b43da7e99f74011ce4b8c53b00a015f--pop-art-portraits-portrait-art.jpg" /></a>
          <a class="swiper-slide" href=""><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1b/43/da/1b43da7e99f74011ce4b8c53b00a015f--pop-art-portraits-portrait-art.jpg" /></a>
          <a class="swiper-slide" href=""><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1b/43/da/1b43da7e99f74011ce4b8c53b00a015f--pop-art-portraits-portrait-art.jpg" /></a>
          <a class="swiper-slide" href=""><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1b/43/da/1b43da7e99f74011ce4b8c53b00a015f--pop-art-portraits-portrait-art.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем решение есть, чуть переделал.
Суть, есть левая стрелка, я ей присвоил ордер 1, есть правая стрелка я ей присвоил ордер 3, есть центр где слайды, я присвоил ордер 2, далее у стрелок сделал маргин чтоб от слайдов были отступы, ну и убрал там лишнее. Добавил где надо флекс, центрование по флексу алигн.

```js
 var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
   slidesPerView: 4,
   spaceBetween: 15, //отступы между слайдами
   navigation: {
     nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
     prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
   },
   breakpoints: {
     700: {
       slidesPerView: 4,
       loopedSlides: 4,
       spaceBetween: 15
     },
     500: {
       slidesPerView: 2,
       loopedSlides: 2,
       spaceBetween: 10
     },
     350: {
       slidesPerView: 1,
       loopedSlides: 1,
       spaceBetween: 20
     }
   }
 });
```

```css
.allblock{
  max-width: 900px;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px;
}
.block-left{
  width:60%;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.block-right{
  width:40%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.block-right h2{
  font-size:20px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}


.swiperc{
position: relative;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  order:2;
}

.swiper-vertical>.swiper-wrapper {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.swiper-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  transition-property: transform;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.swiper-android .swiper-slide,
.swiper-wrapper {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0, 0);
}

.swiper-pointer-events {
  touch-action: pan-y;
}

.swiper-pointer-events.swiper-vertical {
  touch-action: pan-x;
}

.swiper-slide {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition-property: transform;
}

.swiper-slide-invisible-blank {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.swiper-autoheight,
.swiper-autoheight .swiper-slide {
  height: auto;
}

.swiper-autoheight .swiper-wrapper {
  align-items: flex-start;
  transition-property: transform, height;
}

.swiper-3d,
.swiper-3d.swiper-css-mode .swiper-wrapper {
  perspective: 1200px;
}

.swiper-3d .swiper-cube-shadow,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-right,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-top,
.swiper-3d .swiper-wrapper {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-right,
.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-top {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 10;
}

.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-left {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-right {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-top {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

.swiper-3d .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

.swiper-css-mode>.swiper-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.swiper-css-mode>.swiper-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.swiper-css-mode>.swiper-wrapper>.swiper-slide {
  scroll-snap-align: start start;
}

.swiper-horizontal.swiper-css-mode>.swiper-wrapper {
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.swiper-vertical.swiper-css-mode>.swiper-wrapper {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.swiper-centered>.swiper-wrapper::before {
  content: '';
  flex-shrink: 0;
  order: 9999;
}

.swiper-centered.swiper-horizontal>.swiper-wrapper>.swiper-slide:first-child {
  margin-inline-start: var(--swiper-centered-offset-before);
}

.swiper-centered.swiper-horizontal>.swiper-wrapper::before {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  width: var(--swiper-centered-offset-after);
}

.swiper-centered.swiper-vertical>.swiper-wrapper>.swiper-slide:first-child {
  margin-block-start: var(--swiper-centered-offset-before);
}

.swiper-centered.swiper-vertical>.swiper-wrapper::before {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1px;
  height: var(--swiper-centered-offset-after);
}

.swiper-centered>.swiper-wrapper>.swiper-slide {
  scroll-snap-align: center center;
}

.swiper-virtual.swiper-css-mode .swiper-wrapper::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.swiper-virtual.swiper-css-mode.swiper-horizontal .swiper-wrapper::after {
  height: 1px;
  width: var(--swiper-virtual-size);
}

.swiper-virtual.swiper-css-mode.swiper-vertical .swiper-wrapper::after {
  width: 1px;
  height: var(--swiper-virtual-size);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: swiper-icons;
  src: url('data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64, 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');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-button-prev {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  z-index: 10;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.swiper-button-next:hover,
.swiper-button-prev:hover{
color: #FF2525;
}
.swiper-button-next.swiper-button-disabled,
.swiper-button-prev.swiper-button-disabled {
  opacity: .35;
  cursor: auto;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.swiper-button-next:after,
.swiper-button-prev:after {
  font-family: swiper-icons;
  text-transform: none !important;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-transform: none;
  font-variant: initial;
  line-height: 1;
}
.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-rtl .swiper-button-next {
  left: 0;
  margin-right: 15px;
  right: auto;
  order: 1;
}
.swiper-button-prev:after,
.swiper-rtl .swiper-button-next:after {
  content: 'prev';
}
.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-rtl .swiper-button-prev {
  right:0;
  margin-left: 15px;
  left: auto;
  order: 3;
}
.swiper-button-next:after,
.swiper-rtl .swiper-button-prev:after {
  content: 'next';
}

.swiper-button-lock {
  display: none;
}

.swiper-pagination {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .3s opacity;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 10;
}

.swiper-pagination.swiper-pagination-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

.swiper-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-bullets,
.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-horizontal,
.swiper-pagination-custom,
.swiper-pagination-fraction {
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  transform: scale(.33);
  position: relative;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet-active-main {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet-active-prev {
  transform: scale(.66);
}

.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet-active-prev-prev {
  transform: scale(.33);
}

.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet-active-next {
  transform: scale(.66);
}

.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet-active-next-next {
  transform: scale(.33);
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  width: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-width, var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-size, 8px));
  height: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-height, var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-size, 8px));
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-color, #000);
  opacity: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-opacity, .2);
}

button.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.swiper-pagination-clickable .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet:only-child {
  display: none !important;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  opacity: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-opacity, 1);
  background: var(--swiper-pagination-color, var(--swiper-theme-color));
}

.swiper-pagination-vertical.swiper-pagination-bullets,
.swiper-vertical>.swiper-pagination-bullets {
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(0px, -50%, 0);
}

.swiper-pagination-vertical.swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet,
.swiper-vertical>.swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  margin: var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-vertical-gap, 6px) 0;
  display: block;
}

.swiper-pagination-vertical.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic,
.swiper-vertical>.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 8px;
}

.swiper-pagination-vertical.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet,
.swiper-vertical>.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: .2s transform, .2s top;
}

.swiper-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet,
.swiper-pagination-horizontal.swiper-pagination-bullets .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  margin: 0 var(--swiper-pagination-bullet-horizontal-gap, 4px);
}

.swiper-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic,
.swiper-pagination-horizontal.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.swiper-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet,
.swiper-pagination-horizontal.swiper-pagination-bullets.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  transition: .2s transform, .2s left;
}

.swiper-horizontal.swiper-rtl>.swiper-pagination-bullets-dynamic .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  transition: .2s transform, .2s right;
}

.swiper-pagination-progressbar {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  position: absolute;
}

.swiper-pagination-progressbar .swiper-pagination-progressbar-fill {
  background: var(--swiper-pagination-color, var(--swiper-theme-color));
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scale(0);
  transform-origin: left top;
}

.swiper-rtl .swiper-pagination-progressbar .swiper-pagination-progressbar-fill {
  transform-origin: right top;
}

.swiper-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-progressbar,
.swiper-pagination-progressbar.swiper-pagination-horizontal,
.swiper-pagination-progressbar.swiper-pagination-vertical.swiper-pagination-progressbar-opposite,
.swiper-vertical>.swiper-pagination-progressbar.swiper-pagination-progressbar-opposite {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.swiper-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-progressbar.swiper-pagination-progressbar-opposite,
.swiper-pagination-progressbar.swiper-pagination-horizontal.swiper-pagination-progressbar-opposite,
.swiper-pagination-progressbar.swiper-pagination-vertical,
.swiper-vertical>.swiper-pagination-progressbar {
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.swiper-pagination-lock {
  display: none;
}

.swiper-scrollbar {
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.swiper-horizontal>.swiper-scrollbar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1%;
  bottom: 3px;
  z-index: 50;
  height: 5px;
  width: 98%;
}

.swiper-vertical>.swiper-scrollbar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  top: 1%;
  z-index: 50;
  width: 5px;
  height: 98%;
}

.swiper-scrollbar-drag {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.swiper-scrollbar-cursor-drag {
  cursor: move;
}

.swiper-scrollbar-lock {
  display: none;
}

.swiper-zoom-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.swiper-zoom-container>canvas,
.swiper-zoom-container>img,
.swiper-zoom-container>svg {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.swiper-slide-zoomed {
  cursor: move;
}

.swiper-lazy-preloader {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -21px;
  margin-top: -21px;
  z-index: 10;
  transform-origin: 50%;
  animation: swiper-preloader-spin 1s infinite linear;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 4px solid var(--swiper-preloader-color, var(--swiper-theme-color));
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top-color: transparent;
}

.swiper-lazy-preloader-white {
  --swiper-preloader-color: #fff;
}

.swiper-lazy-preloader-black {
  --swiper-preloader-color: #000;
}

@keyframes swiper-preloader-spin {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.swiper .swiper-notification {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1000;
}

.swiper-free-mode>.swiper-wrapper {
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.swiper-grid>.swiper-wrapper {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.swiper-grid-column>.swiper-wrapper {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.swiper-fade.swiper-free-mode .swiper-slide {
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.swiper-fade .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
  transition-property: opacity;
}

.swiper-fade .swiper-slide .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.swiper-fade .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-fade .swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide-active {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.swiper-cube {
  overflow: visible;
}

.swiper-cube .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-cube .swiper-slide .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.swiper-cube.swiper-rtl .swiper-slide {
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
}

.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide-active {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-next,
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-next+.swiper-slide,
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-prev {
  pointer-events: auto;
  visibility: visible;
}

.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-right,
.swiper-cube .swiper-slide-shadow-top {
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.swiper-cube .swiper-cube-shadow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .6;
  z-index: 0;
}

.swiper-cube .swiper-cube-shadow:before {
  content: '';
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  filter: blur(50px);
}

.swiper-flip {
  overflow: visible;
}

.swiper-flip .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.swiper-flip .swiper-slide .swiper-slide {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.swiper-flip .swiper-slide-active,
.swiper-flip .swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide-active {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.swiper-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-bottom,
.swiper-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-left,
.swiper-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-right,
.swiper-flip .swiper-slide-shadow-top {
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.swiper-creative .swiper-slide {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition-property: transform, opacity, height;
}

.swiper-cards {
  overflow: visible;
}

.swiper-cards .swiper-slide {
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.swiper-slide>img {
border: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
}
.swiper-slide>img:hover {
  border: 2px solid #FF2525;
}
.swiper-slide img{
  width: 100%;
}




.allblock{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}







html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;}
html{-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section,summary{display:block;}
audio,canvas,video{display:inline-block;}
audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0;}
[hidden]{display:none;}
a{outline:none; text-decoration: none;}
abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted;}
pre{white-space:pre;white-space:pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word;}
sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;}
sup{top:-0.5em;}
sub{bottom:-0.25em;}
fieldset{border:1px solid #c0c0c0;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em;}
button,input,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:100%;margin:0;}
button,input{line-height:normal;}
button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer;}
button[disabled],input[disabled]{cursor:default;}
input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;}
input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none;}
button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0;}
textarea{overflow:auto;vertical-align:top;}
input:focus,button:focus,select:focus,textarea:focus{outline:none;}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: transparent;}
:focus::-moz-placeholder          {color: transparent;}
:focus:-moz-placeholder           {color: transparent;}
:focus:-ms-input-placeholder      {color: transparent;}
select{cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7.4.1/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="allblock">
  <div class="block-left">
    Левая колонка
  </div>

  <div class="block-right">
  <h2>Куртка зимняя, на меху ноуминус</h2>
    Выберите цветов товара
    <br /><br />

    <div class="swiperc">
      <div class="swiper">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <a class="swiper-slide" href=""><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1b/43/da/1b43da7e99f74011ce4b8c53b00a015f--pop-art-portraits-portrait-art.jpg" /></a>
          <a class="swiper-slide" href=""><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1b/43/da/1b43da7e99f74011ce4b8c53b00a015f--pop-art-portraits-portrait-art.jpg" /></a>
          <a class="swiper-slide" href=""><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1b/43/da/1b43da7e99f74011ce4b8c53b00a015f--pop-art-portraits-portrait-art.jpg" /></a>
          <a class="swiper-slide" href=""><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1b/43/da/1b43da7e99f74011ce4b8c53b00a015f--pop-art-portraits-portrait-art.jpg" /></a>
          <a class="swiper-slide" href=""><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1b/43/da/1b43da7e99f74011ce4b8c53b00a015f--pop-art-portraits-portrait-art.jpg" /></a>
          <a class="swiper-slide" href=""><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1b/43/da/1b43da7e99f74011ce4b8c53b00a015f--pop-art-portraits-portrait-art.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```